# Adding custom prop to React-Native element?

Tags: react-native, element

I am trying to add custom prop to `<Pressable/>`. The solution I tried is:

```
type StyledButtonProps = {
    correct: boolean,
    clicked: boolean
  }

const button = () => <Pressable></Pressable>
const StyledButton = React.cloneElement(button, {correct, clicked}) //Here this error comes at "button": 
      Argument of type '() => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type
      'ReactElement<{ correct: [boolean, Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>];
      clicked: [boolean, Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>]; }, string | 
      JSXElementConstructor<...>>'
```

And I will use it like this:

```
render(
   <StyledButton onPress={...} correct={...} clicked={...} /> 
)
```

Here also comes warning: JSX element type 'StyledButton' doesnot have any construct or call signatures.

I couldn't find similar case, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React, to customize and add logic to a component, we create a component that renders the original and adds the styling or logic.
So just create a new component that gets every prop that `Pressable` gets, and the new props.

```
import { Pressable, PressableProps } from "react-native";

interface StyledButtonProps extends PressableProps {
    correct: boolean;
    clicked: boolean;
}

const StyledButton = ({ correct, clicked, ...other }: StyledButtonProps) => { // other - any other prop
    // ...
    return <Pressable {...other} />; // This way you pass all original Pressable props
}
```

Comment: Thank you now more understable. Can you edit your answer due to types that I added to my question? I will test it out and accept

Comment: @AnthonSanthez I added the types - its an extension for `Pressable` props

Comment: Thank you very much. It will be StyledButtonProps. It works, accepting answer.

Comment: I cannot style the element due to its own props, they are not reachable inside element's scope. Can you help? I am tring to reach the "correct" prop's value inside "style" prop but it is undefined.  The element is this: <StyledButton
              correct={userAnswer?.correctAnswer === answer}
              clicked={userAnswer?.answer === answer}
              onPress={...}
              style={{
                backgroundColor: correct ? "green" : "red"
              }}
              >